# Play Multitrack Video In FFplay

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got a .ts file with multiple video streams contained therein, but when I try to play it in FFplay it only shows the first mapped video.

Is it possible to play other video tracks within the file using FFplay? -map doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: How is `-map` not working for you? Is there an error? Does ffplay hang? What command are you using exactly? Could you please add more details?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke  Each of the ff* tools has their own set of options. `-map` is not declared for ffplay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pre-select a video stream for playback, use `-vst` i.e.

```
ffplay video.mp4 -vst v:2
```

This will play the third video stream if it exists, else show black.

Once playback starts, as @LordNeckbeard says, you can press <kbd>v</kbd> to cycle through available video streams. (Should you start ffplay by specifying a non-existent video stream, this doesn't seem to work).

Answer (score 1):

Use the <kbd>v</kbd> key to cycle video streams.

Refer to the end of `ffplay -h` for other interactive commands. Note that it will not re-draw the window in case the video streams vary in width x height.

Comment: To select at cmd line, use `-vst v:2` to play the third video stream.

Comment: @Gyan That should be another answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, my streams actually are of varying aspect ratio, though some are not, I will definitely use this in some cases.